# UPDATE not working with INNER JOIN on FOREIGN KEY

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working on a tool that updates products prices in a website. I'm currently stuck on a query that has to update special price on a product which is linked with a primary key in another table:

```
TABLE product_special

product_id is the FK here

product_id | customer_group_id | price
--------------------------------------
 15468     | 1                 | 5,49
 15468     | 2                 | 3,60
 15468     | 6                 | 2,34

----------------------------------------

TABLE product

product_id is PK here

product_id | sku                 | price
--------------------------------------
 15468     | 255                 | 5,49
 15468     | 500                 | 3,60
 15468     | 5377                | 2,34
```

I take the sku and prices from an Excel table and this is what I came up with so far but it's not updating the prices in product_special:

```php
foreach ($priceList as $sku => $price) {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE product_special 
            INNER JOIN product ON product.product_id = product_special.product_id 
            SET price = :price
            WHERE sku = :sku AND customer_group_id = 1;");
    $stmt->bindParam(':price',  $price);
    $stmt->bindParam(':sku', $sku);
    if ($stmt->execute()){
        $message = "<span style=\"color: #c4000b;\">Successfully updated client prices.</span>";
    };
}
```

Comment: I think it's because your fields "price" and "sku" are ambiguous as they exist in both tables. Change it to `SET product_special.price = :price WHERE product_special.sku = :sku`

Also you might consider using aliases so you don't have to type "product_Special" every time

Comment: Why do you join the tables? Can't you just update the price of product_special where customer_group_id = 1?

Comment: @TommyBs Yes, you are right. I just changed "SET price = :price" to "SET product_special.price = :price" and it's working. Thank you.

Comment: I've updated this to an answer so you can accept so others can see this is resolved if they have a similar problem

Comment: @forpas It's not working without JOIN.

Comment: You want to update the column price of product_special where customer_group_id = 1 with a value that you supply as a parameter. You don't need to join to another table unless you want to make sure that there exists the same product in table product with that sku. If this is the case then ok. If not then you don't need the join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because your fields "price" and "sku" are ambiguous as they exist in both tables. Change it to 
`SET product_special.price = :price WHERE product_special.sku = :sku`

Also you might consider using aliases so you don't have to type "product_Special" every time